# Rails + Capistrano + Git: Steps to successfully deploy an app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh

We use git for version control. Right now only my account seems to be able to deploy successfully to a remote server for several apps, but I don't know why. I would like to set it up so that deploying works for other people at my company, but I don't really have the full picture laid out in my head so I don't know what needs to be done.

To me it seems like whoever wants to deploy needs a: user account on the server, an account on github, and permission to pull...? However, other users seem to have the notorious `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` and other errors.

Can anyone provide a short list of what I need to do on the server (make an account, add ssh keys or something?) and git (ssh keys again? not sure) to get the deploy to work?

Comment: You need ssh keys on the server for all of the machines that might deploy an app at some point.  That's causing the error you're seeing

Comment: If you're all using the same git repository, and the same username when deploying, then the ssh keys should be the only thing you need

Comment: So for each user on each machine that wants to deploy, I have to copy that user's ssh key and paste it onto the authorized_keys of the user who will deploy (whether it's a communal user or a specific one)?

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano assumes you can `ssh` into the server you are deploying to. You are probably using a communal `apps`, `deployer`, or some other app-specific user to deploy your app. This will be the user that is set in your deploy.rb file.

You will need to copy everyone's public key into the authorized_keys of whatever your deploying user is. That is just how Capistrano works.